# Create a file in a filesystem

Tags: linux, file, system

I've been requested to run a code on a file in a file system I had to create.
(I created the fs using mkfs and then mounted it with another directory: /home/may/new_place (the original fs appears on my desktop - 8.6GB filesystem)
My question is, can you even create a file in a filesystem? I can't even transfer a file into it, so can't execute my code.

I'm really new to this.. thank you all

(P.S. I'm using linux xubunto OS)

Comment: did you mount the filesystem with the write flag?

Comment: no. why? I used mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb and then created a directory new_place in my home directory. then mount: mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb /home/may/new_place

Answer (score 0):

are you able to touch any files  -- with touch command -- also open a sample file -- write echo $HOSTNAME - save it - chmod u+x  and run it  -- see if you are able to execute the file

Comment: can you be more clear with these instructions? As I've said, I'm new to this.. I entered "echo $HOSTNAME" and it print the host. what do I have to save now?